# In active salesforce system user( formerly called tracking user)

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have integrated a salescloud instance with marketing cloud using marketing cloud connect. We have created a Salesforce system user and completed the integration.We are on a multi org structure.

The clients now want to make the salesforce system user inactive for two weeks so that they can work on data migration activities in salescloud.

will the integration with marketing cloud gets effected when we make the salesforce system user inactive?will we lose the  Business units integration with salescloud.

Comment: Hi Vishnu..how are you getting along? Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The integration user (tracking user) is required to establish connection between the two clouds. Making the SF user inactive will break the link between the clouds , meaning you will have to reconnect them .

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand we have to re integrate all the BU's too, considering that we have a multi org structure. Can you please  point me to any document on salesforce help.

Comment: This is true. I would advise working around the need to deactivate these users . The multi-org adds an extra layer of complexity

Comment: There is no documentation on this particular process, but you should be able to read documentation on connecting the clouds and it should be good to go. https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/